# About lambdas, conversions to function pointers and visibility of private data members

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, language-lawyer

Consider the following example:

```
#include <cassert>

struct S {
    auto func() { return +[](S &s) { s.x++; }; }
    int get() { return x; }

private:
    int x{0};
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.func()(s);
    assert(s.get() == 1);
}
```

It compiles both with G++ and clang, so I'm tempted to expect that is allowed by the standard.
However, the lambda has no capture list and it cannot have it because of the `+` that forces the conversion to a function pointer. Therefore, I expected it was not allowed to access private data members of `S`.
Instead, it behaves more or less how if it was defined as a static member function.

So far, so good. If I knew it before, I would have used this trick often to avoid writing redundant code.

What I'd like to know now is where in the standard (the working draft is fine) this is defined, for I've not been able to find the section, the bullet or whatever that rules about it.
Is there any limitation for the lambda or it works *exactly* as if it was defined as a static member function?

Comment: In case it helps, if you change the lambda to a struct defined in the function and return a function pointer to a static function it also compiles.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the weird close vote... I think this is about as on-topic as a question gets

Comment: @SirGuy I didn't see the close vote indeed. The most stupid way to spend a vote I've ever seen here on SO actually. My two cents. We have a _language-lawyer_ tag but we can't ask about the standard? Curious reasoning.

Comment: The close vote is super-weird: it's for _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.”_ How does any of that apply to this question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For lambda expressions inside the member function, according to [§8.4.5.1/2 Closure types [expr.prim.lambda.closure]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#2):

> The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.

That means the lambda closure type will be declared inside the member function, i.e. a local class. And according to [§14/2 Member access control [class.access]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#2):

(emphasis mine)

> A member of a class can also access all the names to which the class has access. **A local class of a member
>   function may access the same names that the member function itself may access**.

That means for the lambda expression itself, it could access the `private` members of `S`, same as the member function `func`.

And [§8.4.5.1/7 Closure types [expr.prim.lambda.closure]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#7):

(emphasis mine)

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with no lambda-capture whose constraints (if any) are satisfied has a conversion function to pointer to function with C++ language linkage having the same parameter and return types as the closure type's function call operator. ... **The value returned by this conversion function is the address of a function F that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type's function call operator.**

That means when the converted function pointer gets invoked the same rule applies.

Comment: I would mention also that _The value returned by this conversion function is the address of a function F that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type's function call operator_. That's what I missed reading it the first time.

Comment: @skypjack I didn't get this confusion from your question, well I'll add it to the answer later.

Comment: More than being confused, I didn't get the (let me say) _equivalence_ between the function resulting from the conversion and the closure type. Once I got it, everything became clear. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

> However, the lambda has no capture list and it cannot have it because of the `+` that forces the conversion to a function pointer.

`+` does not *force* a conversion to a function pointer, but adds a conversion operator to pointer to function for you to use as an *option*. Lambda remains a lambda, with all the access privileges granted to it, i.e. it may access the same names that the member function itself may access.

Comment: How does `+` not cause the conversion operator to be used?

Comment: @DavisHerring The standard says `+` causes the conversion operator to be defined, not defined and used.

Comment: Really?  [expr.prim.lambda]/6 simply says that a conversion function [template] exists if there are no captures.